# After loggin in Android Mobile app, in button click open asp dot net Mvc website in webview without loggin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api, dot

I have both Android Mobile app & website of my project .My Question is that As User is already logged in inside Android Mobile app & now in button click ,I need to open one section of my asp dot net Mvc website inside Android Mobile app in webview , without login in website. what changes I need to do in my Asp dot net Mvc website in order to achieve this .As database is same for both . What i need to do so i can perform authentication in website backend, so user dont need to authenticate again in website and can direclty open website one section .